# Drop Procedure with bad name (MSSQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I messed up and used sp_rename incorrectly and now I can't drop the procedure that was "created".

What I did was...

```
EXEC sp_rename '[schema].[OldSPName]','[schema].[OldSPName_TMP]'
```

What I expected was to get a new procedure like this `'schema.OldSPName_TMP'` but what I got was `'schema.[schema].[OldSPName_TMP]'`. So I'm trying to drop it but it's giving me the error that...

> DROP PROCEDURE does not allow specifying the database name as a prefix to the object name

I was reading that using the schema as part of the new name in sp_rename would create a "buggy name", but I did not find anything about fixing it when you create the buggy name.

Anyone know how to drop this procedure?

Comment: The name of that procedure is now properly escaped as `[schema].[[schema]].[OldSPName_TMP]]]` (thank you, `QUOTENAME`), so drop that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `"`:

```
DROP PROCEDURE schema."[schema].[OldSPName_TMP]";
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=53d39333c9a3be1cff27d4d930988cc7)**

Answer (score 1):

You can just rename it correctly

```sql
EXEC sp_rename '[schema].[[schema]].[OldSPName_TMP]]]', 'OldSPName_TMP', 'OBJECT';
```

Note that the second parameter should be just the name, with no schema and no brackets. This was the mistake you made the first time.