# Rebuild or Reorganize indexes

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, fragmentation

I want to reorganize or rebuild indexes. I know the sql to perform this action on all indexes in a table is

```
alter index all on table_name reorganize;
```

But I only want to rebuild or reorganize if fragmentation percentage on each index is between a certain range. Is this possible to do?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above alter table is product specific.)

Comment: While making recommendations is usually off-topic, in this instance you can avoid re-inventing the wheel by making use of [sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html)

Comment: "*I want to reorganize or rebuild indexes.*" - Why?

Answer (score -3):

Here is a procedure what I wrote

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ixRebuild @fillfactor int = 100, @Force bit = 0, @Schema varchar(255) = NULL, @Table  varchar(255) = NULL, @PkOnly bit = 0
AS
/*
 * ixRebuild
 * Rebuild all indices in a database.
 * Indices with >30% fragmentation are rebuilt.
 * Indices with >6%  fragmentation are just reorganised.
 * 
 * The default fill factor is 100%.
 *
 * Required permissions are:
 * GRANT VIEW DATABASE STATE TO <user>
 * GRANT ALTER TO <user>
 * GRANT EXEC ON ixRebuild TO <user>
 * 
 * Created 17/9/08 by rwb.
 */
BEGIN
    DECLARE @db int
    DECLARE @tab varchar(256)
    DECLARE @ix int
    DECLARE @ixName varchar(256)
    DECLARE @frag float
    DECLARE @cmd varchar(1024)
    DECLARE @type int
    
    DECLARE c CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
        SELECT DISTINCT s.database_id, s.index_id, i.name, 
            Convert(float, s.avg_fragmentation_in_percent),
            ss.name + '.' + t.name AS tableName,
            i.type
        FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(Db_Id(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) s
            INNER JOIN sys.indexes i  ON s.object_id = i.object_id  AND s.index_id = i.index_id
            INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON i.object_id = t.object_id
            INNER JOIN sys.schemas ss ON t.schema_id = ss.schema_id
        WHERE (@Schema IS NULL OR ss.name = @Schema)
            AND (@Table IS NULL OR t.name = @Table)
            AND (@PkOnly = 0 OR i.is_primary_key = 1)
            AND (
                @Force = 1
                OR (
                    avg_fragmentation_in_percent > 6
                    AND page_count > 100 -- rebuilding small indices does nothing
                    AND i.name IS NOT NULL -- for tables with no PK
                )
            )
        -- DISTINCT because ys.dm_db_index_physical_stats
        -- contains a row for each part of a partitioned index on a partitioned table.
    OPEN c
    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @db, @ix, @ixName, @frag, @tab, @type
    WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0
    BEGIN
        PRINT Db_Name( @db ) + ' / ' + @tab + ' / ' + @ixName + '   ' + Cast(@frag as varchar(16))
        SET @cmd = ''
        
        IF @frag < 10.0 AND @Force = 0
        BEGIN
            SET @cmd = 'ALTER INDEX ' + @ixName + ' ON ' + @tab + ' REORGANIZE'
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @cmd = 'ALTER INDEX ' + @ixName + ' ON ' + @tab + 
                CASE 
                    WHEN @type IN (1, 2) THEN ' REBUILD WITH (FILLFACTOR = ' + Cast(@fillfactor AS varchar(4)) + ')'
                    ELSE ''
                END
        END
        
        RAISERROR(@cmd, 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT;
        
        EXEC (@cmd)
        
        FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @db, @ix, @ixName, @frag, @tab, @type
    END
    CLOSE c
    DEALLOCATE c

END
```

Answer (score -3):

Generally rebuilding all indexes of a table is a bad idea, because some can have no fragmentation, while some other can be horribly bloated !
Rebuiliding index is a heavy process and is blocking the access of the table the time to do so, except in ONLINE mode available only with the Enterprise version.

So you need to rebuild only under certains circumstances... Authors (which I think due to my old age in RDBMS, I am a part of them...) agree to say that small tables don't care and a percentage of fragmentation under 30 does not matter.
I alway add some complexity over these ideas, with another point : "big" rows of table or indexes (1600 bytes is a max for an index) will appear always to be fragmented, but are not... This because evaluating a frag percent take in account a percent of free space on a page and with a 8 Kb page, a natural no-recoverable space will stay inside the page (20% max for an index and 49 % max for a table).

So a good practice is to mix all those considerations to build a proper code to rebuild or defrag all objects includes in your database.

As an example, a short code to do so, can be :

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(max) = N'';
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + CASE WHEN i.name IS NULL
               THEN N'ALTER TABLE [' + s.name + '].[' + o.name + '] REBUILD;'
            WHEN avg_fragmentation_in_percent > 30
               THEN N'ALTER INDEX [' + i.name + '] ON [' + s.name + '].[' + o.name + '] REBUILD;'
            ELSE N'ALTER INDEX [' + i.name + '] ON [' + s.name + '].[' + o.name + '] REORGANIZE;'
         END
FROM   sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) AS ips
         JOIN sys.objects AS o ON ips.object_id = o.object_id
         JOIN sys.schemas AS s ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
         JOIN sys.indexes AS i ON ips.object_id = i.object_id AND ips.index_id = i.index_id
WHERE  ips.page_count > 64 AND  avg_fragmentation_in_percent > 10;
EXEC (@SQL);
```

Comment: 10 percent fragmentation is much too aggressive. Also use `QUOTENAME` not `[]` to quote names

Comment: I never use QUOTENAME function because of performances considerations and heavier query to script while a simple pair of bracket can do the same ! Also QUOTENAME returns a NVARCHAR(258) instaed of a NVARCHAR(130) that should be done...

Comment: As you can see from this fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/xUs3V0eH you are not escaping closing brackets `]` correctly, causing SQL injection. Not sure what your issue is with performance, or with `nvarchar(258)` nor where you get `nvarchar(130)` from, either way the final SQL will be `nvarchar(max)`

Comment: [Don’t Rely On Square Brackets To Protect You From SQL Injection: Use QUOTENAME Instead](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/dont-rely-on-square-brackets-to-protect-you-from-sql-injection/)

Comment: [Drop Procedure with bad name (MSSQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71413538/14868997)

Comment: @ErikDarling there is no need to protect against sql injections in this case as long as all names are taken from the system views. If someone already has possible injections in object names then this person must be taken as far as possible from git, databases and programming in general.   Also, I believe that there is special place in Hell for all those people who name objects in such a way that someone needs to quote names after that :)

Comment: @IgorBorisenko the point is that when you put bad code examples on the internet like this one, people tend to follow them in places where it could leave them open to SQL injection. I agree it may not be explicitly necessary in this case, but it's still not a good idea.